# How to restart a DOCKER container and connect to its powershell

Tags: docker

I have a stopped windows container named "mycake" 
[image]

Now I would like to start it again and access to its powershell inside the container. How would I do that. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the downvote? what is the issue with the question?

Comment: `docker start` and `docker exec` and `docker run sh` are all very well-known I think.

Comment: But I'm new to them and had tried several times before asking !!

Comment: I am new to this too. Very useful question

Comment: by the way, what is the advantage of using powershell here? the good old Command Prompt works just as well with a linux container

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I can do  something like this

Remove the current container

```
docker container rm mycake
```

and then start a new container

```
docker container run -it --name mycake d_layerfiles powershell
```

I'm not sure that is the best way

Comment: instead removing the container u can also use same container using below command   `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash`

Comment: I tried but it does not work. I got the error docker container exec -it 71f79c3cf92e /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 71f79c3cf92e72bf64222c30dfe05ffff50b2910cebddf7c4494f766b629ff73 is not running

Comment: This approach is fine.  It's what you need to do because the container process exited (successfully).  You could launch a different container from the same image, but the exited container is exited.

Comment: Ok. I thought removing container would be a bad practice. Once I have more experience with docker, I will probably can evaluate myself

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can only start a bash shell in a RUNNING container. Start a container by clicking the triangle start icon in Docker Desktop.

[image]

Then, as Hitesh Ghuge explained, this works very well, type this in a Powershell or Command Prompt terminal to get a linux command prompt from a linux container:

```
C:\> docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
root@dfd92a569d54:/mnt#
```

Note that in the Docker Desktop app, the Container Name has an icon to copy the hex numeric container id to your clipboard. You may also use the name as id, e.g. laughing_hertz, or the visible part of the hex id, e.g. dfd92a569d54.

(The current directory in the linux shell, e.g. /mnt, probably depends on how the container was originally created, or on the situation on previous exit)